# Timeout writing or reading from the endpoint, and communicating format problem (wireshark + pyusb)

Tags: ubuntu, usb, wireshark, pyusb

I've bought a USB spectroscopy from a small company, they only offer me the driver for the window platform, however I am planning to use that device on ubuntu, so I decide to use the wireshark to capture the packet on windows, then replay it on ubuntu to capture the data.

Things going were just fun on windows, with that offered driver and software, I have caught the data from wireshark, and I've figured out where and how my data were transmitted (in the leftover capture data part).

[Captured data on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBZR0.png)

The next step is to replay that message on ubuntu, by using PyUSB, i have figure out the right endpoint for the communication, however when I try to read or writing on that endpoint, it always pop out the [errno 110] Operation timed out. I don't know what is wrong and I use the wireshark on ubuntu to monitor the usb communication on ubuntu, then I find out that when I try to write on that endpoint, there are communication between the host and my devices, however, the format of the communication is totally different from packet capture on windows.

I don't know why it is different on ubuntu, and I don't know if the error is due to that problem.

Can anyone give me any suggestions to figure that devices out on ubuntu?

Many thanks!

[packet capture on ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuLD2.jpg)

Comment: There is probably some setup step that you are missing.  Make sure you examine every USB packet that happens from the time you plug the device into Windows.  You might need to try a different protocol analyzer if wireshark does not show that.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! I recheck all the packets then it finally worked! Thanks a lot!